# How to implement a secure public api

Tags: api, security, httprequest

I build many portal websites for different small retails. They may have some features like leave message, search, load inventories, and etc. I have all my APIs and database located on my own server to receive those requests. However, I want to only limit the requests from the portal sites not expose to others. Since the portal sites do not have user login, how I can make my APIs more secure?

Comment: [Off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stackoverflow. Try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Seems better suited for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's not at all clear what your asking. Do you want to authenticate the requests without the users having any kind of secret? That's probably not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is authentication tokens based on Oauth2. By the way if you give more detail about your occasion people can better help you.